# How to the display the information in an OpenLayers popup as a two column table?

Tags: openlayers-2, table

My pop-up info in OpenLayers is showing its information horizontally (see screenshot below). I would like it to display vertically instead. Is it possible?

[image]

Comment: Please start with mixed case, then you won't receive as many downvotes for not posting in English.

Comment: I assume dayis would like an output with values stacked on top of each other, like a table with one or two columns, rather than a table with two rows 12+ columns

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not possible in OpenLayers directly, it just renders HTML output that comes presumably from geoserver, in this case. This is at least what it looks like [here](http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/getfeatureinfo-control.html), if you check the reponse from the WMS GetFeatureInfo.

I think you would need either

1. check if you can get raw values from geoserver and format as you like or
2. make a custom feature info template on geoserver as described [here](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/tutorials/GetFeatureInfo/index.html)

Comment: If HTML format is requested then, changing the template on the WMS server would be the way to go (assuming you have access to the server).  MapServer and ArcGIS server allow this too (not just GeoServer).  Otherwise you can request other output formats and render it in your OpenLayers client

Answer (score 0):

Update for OpenLayers 4.

You are able to display feature information outside of the map bounding box. This is a cleaner method if you want specific attributes to be displayed. The example can be found on the OpenLayers [Example](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/vector-layer.html) page.